# jquery dialog not closing after ajax login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm using JQuery UI Dialog for a popup login box on my MVC3 application. Currently I've got it working to log the user in and refresh the "login-status" div on the parent page, show the validation errors in the popup if unsuccessful.  However, if I press the cancel button in the login form, the popup doesn't close, and it also doesn't close on a successful login.  Can anyone see something obviously wrong with my code?  Thanks very much.

Log in button click event:

```
$('a#login').click(function (e) {                    
var url = '@Url.Action("LogOnPartial", "Account")';
var dialog = $('<div id="ModalDialog" style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
$.get('@Url.Action("LogOnPartial", "Account", null)', function (response) {
    dialog.html(response)
    dialog.dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        modal: true,           
        width: 500,                       
        closeOnEscape: false,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function () {
                $("#refresh").submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $("#ModalDialog").dialog("close");
                // EDIT - This part now working - solution below:
                //dialog.dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Login form partial view

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "success",  UpdateTargetId = "loginDialog" }, new { @id = "refresh"}))
    {

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <a href="@Url.Content("~/Account/ForgotPassword")">Forgot Password?</a>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Log On" style="display:none" />
    }

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function success(result) {
        if (result.success) {
            $('#loginStatus').load("@Url.Content("~/Account/LogOnStatus")");
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        } 
    }
</script>
```

I can post up controller code too if that is necessary.  Basically if successful it returns `json success = true`, and if not returns the partial view with validation errors.

Comment: does `dialog.dialog("close");` work?

Comment: Ah, thanks yes it does - well, it works for the cancel button, but not for closing the popup automatically after successful login

Answer (score 2):

after executing ajax function `this` is not dialog anymore
you must specify concrete div by id or save `this` of dialog to variable somewhere else

Comment: Good to know about the 'this' statement.  However I have tried `$('#ModalDialog').dialog('destroy').remove();` and `$('#ModalDialog').dialog('close');` as well without success.  It always just leaves an empty popup open

Comment: give me link to page to check what's happen

Comment: I've got nothing uploaded that you could check - it's all on a local machine unfortunately.

Comment: Camel is correct, the $(this) is out of scope and you should be using $('#ModalDialog')

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried using the selectors in my earlier comment but it didn't work. I found a workaround which I've posted below, but this has been a really infuriating and illogical problem. Hopefully I'll find the reason out someday :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    dialog.dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        modal: true,           
        width: 500,                       
        closeOnEscape: false,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function () {
                $("#refresh").submit();
                dialog.dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                dialog.dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that closes the popup whether the login is successful or not.  I need to keep it open and display validation errors in that case which was why I try to close it from the partial view

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround but it feels a bit hacky as the error console briefly shows an error.  Instead of this line:

```
var dialog = $('<div id="ModalDialog" style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
```

I changed it to

```
dialog = $('<div id="ModalDialog" style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
```

which made the variable was global and carried over to partial views.  I was then able to use

```
dialog.dialog('destroy');
```

Infuriating problem - thanks anyway for all the suggestions.

Comment: why you appending body?? if you can place this div on page like other elements(standard way) and then setup this dialog div as dialog (prepare div to be dialog after `$(document).ready`) and then use it on page. i think that is better way of doing this. everything will be prepared and waiting for user action

Comment: and i think that maybe problem is when you create var dialog that exist only in click function but ajax runs asynchronous and maybe as separate function doesn't have access to this variable, i'm guessing but maybe it is true, try to make dialog var more global